# Specific loop in Shortcode

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, shortcode

I'm making shortcode and I'm stuck here. Here is code:

```
add_shortcode('service-shortcode', 'service_shortcode');

function service_shortcode($atts) 
{
extract( shortcode_atts( array(

   'title' => 'Service One',
   'icon' => 'fa-briefcase'

    ), $atts ));
$return_string = '';

$return_string .= '<div class="service">';
    $return_string .= '<div class="container">';
        $return_string .= '<div class="row">';
            $return_string .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">';
                $return_string .= '<div class="service-icon wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="300ms">';
                    $return_string .= '<i class="fa '.$icon.'"></i>';
                $return_string .= '</div>';
                $return_string .= '<div class="text wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="300ms">';
                    $return_string .= '<p>'.$title.'</p>';
                $return_string .= '</div>';
            $return_string .= '</div>';
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    $return_string .= '</div>';
$return_string .= '</div>';

return $return_string;
}
```

Now when ever I put the shortcode it outputs the complete shortcode. What I want is for the first time it outputs complete shortcode and then just output from (div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6") to its closing tag. So the all services will come in a row.. Is there any way to achieve it. Thanks in advance..

Note: I don't want to make custom post type that store each service and call with wp_query ...

Comment: but where is wordpress query / loop? Please paste the full code

Comment: I don't have any wp_query in the shortcode. This is the full shortcode. Hope u got my question :/

Comment: so... there is no loop? so.. what the problem? using the same code for different part pf code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok mate - i got you...
you should really break into 2 shortcodes. One as a wrapper (which is really short) and the other for the content...

**Example:**

```
add_shortcode('servicewrap', 'service_wrapsc');
function service_wrapsc($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<div class="service"><div class="container"><div class="row">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div></div></div>';
}


add_shortcode('servicesingle', 'service_singlesc');
function service_singlesc($atts, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'icon'  => 'fa-briefcase'
    ), $atts));


    return '
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">';
        <div class="service-icon wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="300ms"><i class="fa '.$icon.'"></i></div>
        <div class="text wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <p>'.do_shortcode($content).'</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

**Than... You can do something like**

```
[servicewrap]
    [servicesingle icon=""]Your title here[/servicesingle]
    [servicesingle icon=""]Your title here[/servicesingle]
    [servicesingle icon=""]Your title here[/servicesingle]
[/servicewrap]
```

Comment: Hi, Sagive You explained it very well . Learned new things. but I'm integrating my shortcodes into the tinyMCE button so I'm bit confused on clicking the button it will execute the shortcode which is
[servicewrap]
[servicesingle icon=""]Your title here[/servicesingle]
[/servicewrap] 
But for the next time how it will just execute servicesingle shortcode inside servicewrap shortcode. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: hmm.. well, i use chained dropdowns (2 selects) as my shortcodes helper so i dont have that issuse. i guess you can make it one button and just copy the inside container. i dont see any other way that would offer flexibility - you can also make 2 buttons but i think thats overkill for such a simple shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED 2015 March 16:**

A quick solution would be to use wrapping shortcodes.

```
function service_shortcode_start() {
    $return_string .= '<div class="service">';
        $return_string .= '<div class="container">';
            $return_string .= '<div class="row">';
                 $return_string .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">';

    return $return_string;
}

function service_shortcode_end() {
    $return_string .= '</div>';
        $return_string .= '</div>';
            $return_string .= '</div>';
                 $return_string .= '</div>';

    return $return_string;
}

function service_shortcode( $atts ) 
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
       'title' => 'Service One',
       'icon' => 'fa-briefcase'
        ), $atts ));
    $return_string = '';

    $return_string .= '<div class="service-icon wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="300ms">';
    $return_string .= '<i class="fa '.$icon.'"></i>';
    $return_string .= '</div>';
    $return_string .= '<div class="text wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="300ms">';
    $return_string .= '<p>'.$title.'</p>';
    $return_string .= '</div>';

    return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'service-shortcode', 'service_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'service-shortcode-start', 'service_shortcode_start' );
add_shortcode( 'service-shortcode-end', 'service_shortcode_end' );
```

Example:

```
[service-shortcode-start][service-shortcode title="1" icon="fa-briefcase"][service-shortcode title="2" icon="fa-phone"][service-shortcode title="3" icon="fa-banana"][service-shortcode-end]
```

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for your answer again. I implemented your example we are nearly there. What its doing now it is outputting (div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6") out side the service>container>row. I want it to output inside this right after the after first (div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6") close. Thanks for answer. I'm waiting for your answer :P thanks again...

Comment: I've edited the code to do what I think you said you want; that is, to move the row div up to the start block for your code. If that isn't what you are after, you need to make a jsfiddle that shows the HTML structure you are after.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/a07btqs6/3/)

Comment: Oops, just saw where my problem is. Standby for answer revision.