# Calling Specific Pages with wp query Part II

Tags: custom-field, loop, pages, meta-query

I'm making one page website and I added a custom field on "Page" post type that asks "Use this page as a section:" Yes or No(with dropdown). I called all pages on template-onepage.php(custom template) using wp query

```
<?php $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'pages',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => 50,
  'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'field_5505a81b83234', // field key generated from acf plugin
        'value'   => 'Yes'
   )
 );
 $onepage = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

        <?php if ( $onepage->have_posts() ) : while ( $onepage->have_posts() ) : $onepage->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="section">

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Above I tried to get only those pages that set to Yes from custom field but it showing all pages. I want only those that set to "Yes" through custom field  I asked the question about it so this is part II. Please help. Thanks.

Note: I used Advanced Custom Field for creating the field and the field type is "Select" with two option Yes and No.. Thanks Again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here

- The default `page` post type is `page`, not `pages`
- Your `meta_query` is wrong, it should be an array of an array, not just an array

Your arguments should be

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'field_5505a81b83234', // field key generated from acf plugin
            'value'   => 'Yes'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you Pieter very much again. You solved my problem thanks again. Can u look at this question 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181203/specific-loop-in-shortcode/181214?noredirect=1#comment264717_181214

Thanks.