# Order by menu structure

Tags: wp-query, menus, pages, order

As I'm making one page website. Here is question I asked earlier:

[Calling Specific Pages with wp query Part II](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181270/calling-specific-pages-with-wp-query-part-ii)

As I'm calling all pages by WP_Query which is "order by = ASC" I want to call it "order by menu structure" not menu_order.

For E.g: [image: screenshot]

Now I want home to the top then services then testimonials. depend on menu structure..

How can I achieve it.. Please Help .. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a basic example of what you would consider "menu structure"? For example menus can be nested, what would be the order in such cases?

Comment: @rarst I updated my question. Waiting for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hussy I don't believe there is a method available to query by the Appearance > Menu structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *may* be able to use a WP_Query on `nav_menu_item` since it is its own post type. I've never done this but maybe it would work like you need it to, worth a shot. There are three other possibilities:

## Option 1 - Get Your Nav Menu Items

There's a functions called [`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) which will return you an array of your menu items that you can then loop through and display. Here's an example of how you could use it. There are a few "Gotcha!" here:

- `$item->ID` is the current navigational items ID **not** the `post_id`. The post ID is now `$item->object_id`.
- `$item->title` is the current navigational items title and not necessarily the `post_title` though by default it is, it can still be modified and changed. The most reliable way to get the post title is to use the `object_id` and pass it into `get_the_title()` function.

---

```
$nav_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Main Menu', array(
    'order'                  => 'ASC',                  // List ASCending or DESCending
    'orderby'                => 'title',                // Order by your usual, menu_order, post_title, etc. Check WP_Query
    'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',        // To be honest, I'm not sure why this is an option, leave it be.
    'post_status'            => 'publish',              // If there are private / draft posts in our menu, don't show them
    'output'                 => ARRAY_A,                // Return an Array of Objects
    'output_key'             => 'menu_order',           // Not sure what this does
    'nopaging'               => true,                   // Not sure what this does
    'update_post_term_cache' => false                   // Not sure what this does
) );

if( ! empty( $nav_items ) ) {
    foreach( $nav_items as $item ) {
        echo "{$item->title} - " . get_the_title( $item->object_id );
        echo "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

## Option 2 - Custom Nav Walker

You could just display your menu as is using `wp_nav_menu()` and pass in a [Custom Walker Function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) to modify it's output. An example of this could be automatically pulling that menu items child pages, without actually adding those pages to the physical menu. [Child Walker Class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47903/automatic-submenu)

## Option 3 - Page Menu Order

Usually when I create a website for a client I have a WordPress menu and I also mirror the admin panels page order with Page Attribute `menu_order`. This way you could query pages using [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and `orderby => 'menu_order'`

[image: Image Found on codeholic.in]

---

Other than that, in short there is no easy `orderby => 'My Menu'`, you'll have to find an alternative or a workaround.

Comment: Hi, McGee. Thanks for your answer really well explained .. I know about option 3 as I asked in question not menu_order. Well can u explain a little bit more about wp_get_nav_menu_items() with coding example or any link to tutorial. How can I use it.?? .. Thanks again..

Comment: @Hussy571 I've added an example of how to use `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`. The first parameter passed will be whatever your menu is called. Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure what all the parameters do, I tried messing around with them and got unexpected results. The best references to changes some of these parameters will be The Codex on [`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) and [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: I choose option 3 . couldn't make it with option 1 . :'( . I will post a news question on how to make it with wp_nav_menu_item() .. but again thanks for explanation.

Comment: Option 1, how can I get the item link?

Comment: @ValRob The ID is held in `$item->object_id` so you can pass that to `get_permalink()` or whatever link function you need.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) instead of wp_query() to retrieve the menu items from a particular menu in the menu structure order. Once you've done that, you could loop through the menu items one by one to do with as you wish (including filtering them down further on type or other info). This is assuming all pages are in the menu (which they would need to be if you're using that to understand the order).